# Physical meaning of tensor products and symmetric products for quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-spin, representation-theory

I would like to ask a simple question about quantum mechanics. Consider a 2d Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$ with a orthogonal basis $|x\rangle,|y\rangle$. We can form the $n$-fold tensor product
$$\mathrm{T}^n(\mathbb{C}^2):=\underbrace{\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathbb{C}^2}_n\cong\mathbb{C}^{2^n}$$
and the $n$-fold symmetric product
$$\mathrm{Sym}^n(\mathbb{C}^2)=\mathrm{T}^n(\mathbb{C}^2)\big/\cdots (x\otimes y-y\otimes x)\cdots,\quad\dim=n+1. $$
There is a natural action $\mathrm{SU}(2)\curvearrowright\mathbb{C}^2$, which induces representations
$$\mathrm{SU}(2)\curvearrowright \mathrm{T}^n(\mathbb{C}^2),\quad\mathrm{SU}(2)\curvearrowright\mathrm{Sym}^n(\mathbb{C}^2). $$

I come up with the following statements and want to ask if they are physically sensible. I mainly want to ask Q6 below. However, as an amateur misunderstandings in Q1-Q5 may lead to ill-posednees of Q6.

1. We can say $\mathbb{C}^2$ is the Hilbert space of quantum states of a spin, and $|a\rangle$ is up and $|b\rangle$ is down.
2. A matrix of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ transforms $|a\rangle,|b\rangle$ to another set of orthogonal basis, which means we rotation our apparatus so that up and down change to other directions.
3. $\mathrm{T}^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is the space of states of $n$ spins. For example at each of $n$ different locations, there is one spin of the type. In this system, spins are distinguishable, labelled by location. We have *one* apparatus for measurements at different places. The $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-actions correspond to rotations of the apparatus.
4. $\mathrm{Sym}^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$ is the space of states of $n$ *bosonic* spins. Also $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ means rotation.
5. Every two nonzero unit-length vectors of $\mathbb{C}^2$ are related by an $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-action. This fact corresponds to that for every state of a spin, there is one direction such that the state is definite (not a superposition). Can we say there is only one state, up to rotation?
6. If $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus0$ modulo $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ has a physical meaning, what are physical meanings of $\mathrm{T}^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$ modulo $\mathbb{C}^*$ and $\mathrm{SU}(2)$? How about $\mathrm{Sym}^n(\mathbb{C}^2)$?

Comment: Why does it have to be a spin? All two state systems have the same properties, don't they? And why is there a preferred basis? Which state of the ensemble we prepare is totally up to us. I don't know how that becomes a special case. That "states" rotate in the Hilbert space is a direct consequence of the unitarity, which is a direct consequence of the construction of an ensemble theory.

Comment: Can you provide the reference

Comment: @Amanpawar Sorry, there is no reference for this post. I do math and this comes when I see a quotient theory of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ (symplectic quotient, GIT quotient stuff). I wonder if it has something to do with physics.

Comment: Well, a lot of things in the world behave like generalized rotations... but that's just math. That's not "physics".

Comment: @FlatterMann Can you please tell me up to which among Q1-Q6, there is no physics?

Comment: Physics is the irreversible energy transfer that we can observe in an actual experiment involving quanta. The math that you are listing is basically just histograms over those energy transfers, except that von Neumann didn't use the word histogram when he described the solution theory of the Schroedinger equation with functional analysis. In other words, you are talking about abstracts that don't exist in reality. In a way it's similar to using real numbers and vectors to describe a force. A force is not a real number or an element of R^3. It's that which accelerates a mass.

Comment: The difference is that much of the structure of these histograms is related to our choice to assume statistical independence between individual quantum events. That's not a given in an experiment. If we measure multiple consecutive photons from a laser source we can find strong correlations that are not covered by a naive application of the theory. We have to wait for "a long enough time" for measurements to become independent. However, we can recover those correlations by using a tensor product of single quantum states. These are subtleties that the naive theory does not easily cover.